# ERROR: `elasticsearch` directory is missing in the plugin zip

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

After i triggered the install command for ingest-attachment-6.3.0 plugin installation, i got an error saying that `elasticsearch directory is missing in the plugin zip`

I have install elasticsearch 6.2.3 version.

Please find the error details below.

```
D:\1SearchEngine\elasticsearch-6.2.3\elasticsearch-6.2.3>bin\elasticsearch-plugi
n install file:///d:\1SearchEngine\ingest-attachment\ingest-attachment-6.3.0.zip

-> Downloading file:///d:\1SearchEngine\ingest-attachment\ingest-attachment-6.3.
0.zip
[=================================================] 100%  
ERROR: `elasticsearch` directory is missing in the plugin zip

D:\1SearchEngine\elasticsearch-6.2.3\elasticsearch-6.2.3>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unzip `ingest-attachment-6.3.0.zip` archive and check if there is no another archive inside.

Or, if you have internet connection, just use `sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install ingest-attachment`